# Find out RTP maximum size

Tags: tcp, rtsp, rtp, libpcap, mtu

I have read [RTP Packet maximum size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58097580/rtp-packet-maximum-size) and  [What is the max rtsp(over tcp) packet size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61518156/what-is-the-max-rtspover-tcp-packet-size) but that didn't answer on my problem.

How can I find out what is the max size of rtp/rtsp? is that depend only on MTU  ? there is no way that rtp/rtsp will be bigger than MTU ?

I have change the MTU with `ifconfig eth1 mtu 1000 up` but still I got RTSP packet with 1440 length

Answer (score 0):

> How can I find out what is the max size of rtp/rtsp? is that depend
> only on MTU ? there is no way that rtp/rtsp will be bigger than MTU ?

In practice a `RTP` of 1400 bytes is a good size in 99.9% of time.
There is no real limit as you may use IP level fragmentation and/or Ethernet Jumbo-frame.
In summary, the max size of `RTP` is not dependent on MTU but on the codec/framing in use.

> I have change the MTU with ifconfig eth1 mtu 1000 up but still I got
> RTSP packet with 1440 length

`ifconfig eth1 mtu 1000` set a 1000 MTU on the eth1 interface.

- It is not possible to send larger datagrams than 1000,
- but eth1 is still able to receive larger datagrams.

If you think about it **interface-MTU** is rather different of actual **path-MTU** between two hosts.

If you have such a specific need, you should be looking to implement **MTU path discovery**.